# Show different content on the same page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to show different result in 1 page with links example.
i have 4 items - example1, example2, example3, example4
each of the example has 3 or 4 pages of information depends on the type.

so if want to see the information of example3 type3 i would get that information on page Example3

I don't want to make like 30 pages just for 4 items i want my Menu to look like

Main item Example

Sub Items Example1, Example2, Example3, Example4

and then put links in each sub page with the action thing like:
**php?example=1&type=1 show example1 type1 else if example=1&type=2 show example1 type2 else if example=2&type=1 show example2 type1 and so on~**

If any one can give me an example of how to do it please i would be great full.

if its possible with Wordpress-plugin or any other way i would like to hear it.

Edit:
this is how i tried it and it works but i don't know if action are good to use with Wordpress website i have read on the web people says its not a good choice to use.

```
<?php
    $Example= $_GET['example'];
    if ($Example== 'example1')
    {
    echo "Hello example1";
    }
    if ($Example== 'example2')
    {
    echo "Hello example2";
    }
    if ($Example== 'example3')
    {
    echo "Hello example3";
    }
    if ($Example== 'example4')
    {
    echo "Hello example4";
    }           
</php>
```

And sorry if i made any typo's

Thanks in advance,
Jawido

Comment: Sounds like you want views controlled by a model... [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)? Try the [CodeIgniter Blog Tutorial video](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/). CI is an MVC-built framework.

Comment: Here's a little bit of an old article, but one that gives you the basics to how this works using URL decomposition: http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html It's a series, too.

Comment: i dont know how to build all the class and i use a wordpress website i dont know how to combine those both

Comment: and i dont use any databse for the items its just information i thought i could just type it in <div> and then call those div with the action

Comment: Hmm, didn't see the WordPress parts... Sorry about that. Would [categories](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/categories/) or [tags](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/tags/) work?

Comment: No offence but i don't see any attempt here. Learn some php or hire an coder. You shouldn't expect everything to be spoon feed.

Comment: Itachi i dont want to hire a coder because i want to learn how to do it i have tryed to do it on many ways and i was stuck so i asked my question here. i dont want to be spoon feed because then i would not learn any thing. i was just asking for some guidance like witch way is the best to solve my problem and in the future do it that way.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i will try the tags and categories i will post here if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the custom query to retrieve the information depending upon url query string. Use category to group the posts. For example, posts that falls under category of example1 can be retrieved on page by using

```
    <?php


// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=example1' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

You would want to go through the documentation for Wp_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Use get_post if you want to get the information of individual page.